DEADLOCK... who's victim?
I am trying to make a synthesis of deadlock data for developers.
But the lack I have in my final script is to know which query is the victim.
Here is the code :
DECLARE @DATA_LOCK TABLE(TARGET_DATA XML);

INSERT INTO @DATA_LOCK 
SELECT CAST(target_data AS XML) AS TARGET_DATA
FROM   sys.dm_xe_session_targets st
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions s 
          ON s.address = st.event_session_address
WHERE  s.name = 'system_health'
       AND st.target_name = 'ring_buffer';

WITH 
DATA_SRC AS
(
SELECT X_EVENT.query('.') AS X_EVENT_LOCK
FROM   @DATA_LOCK
       CROSS APPLY 
          TARGET_DATA.nodes('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]')
          AS X_EVENT_DATA(X_EVENT)
),
DATA_LOCKS AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER(ORDER BY X_EVENT_LOCK.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 
                                           'datetimeoffset')) 
          AS DEADLOCK_NUM,
       X_EVENT_LOCK.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 
                          'datetimeoffset') AS DEADLOCK_DATETIME, 
       X_EVENT_LOCK.query('(event/data/value/deadlock)[1]') 
          AS DEADLOCK_GRAPH_XML
FROM   DATA_SRC
),
TD AS
(
SELECT DEADLOCK_NUM, DEADLOCK_DATETIME, DEADLOCK_GRAPH_XML,
       i.query('.') AS XML_VICTIMS,
       v.query('.') AS XML_PROCESS
FROM  DATA_LOCKS
      CROSS APPLY 
         DEADLOCK_GRAPH_XML.nodes('/deadlock/victim-list/victimProcess') 
         AS X(i)
      CROSS APPLY 
         DEADLOCK_GRAPH_XML.nodes('/deadlock/process-list/process') 
         AS V(v)
),
TV AS
(
SELECT DEADLOCK_NUM, DEADLOCK_DATETIME, DEADLOCK_GRAPH_XML,
       i.value('(/victimProcess/@id)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(128)') 
          AS VICTIM_ID
FROM TD
     CROSS APPLY XML_VICTIMS.nodes('/victimProcess[@id]') AS V(i)
),
TP AS
(
SELECT DEADLOCK_NUM, DEADLOCK_DATETIME, 
       i.value('(./@id)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(128)') AS PROCESS_ID,
       i.value('(./@currentdbname)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(128)') AS DATABASE_NAME,
       i.value('(./executionStack/frame/@procname)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(128)')
          AS PROC_NAME1,
       i.value('(./executionStack/frame/@procname)[2]', 'NVARCHAR(128)')
          AS PROC_NAME2,
       i.value('(./executionStack/frame)[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS SQL_QUERY1,
       i.value('(./executionStack/frame)[2]', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS SQL_QUERY2
FROM TD
     CROSS APPLY XML_PROCESS.nodes('/process') AS P(i)
)

SELECT DISTINCT CASE TP.PROCESS_ID  
                   WHEN TV.VICTIM_ID 
                      THEN 'VICTIM !' 
                   ELSE 'Alive...' 
                END AS FINAL_STATE,
       TP.* 
FROM   TP
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TV 
          ON TP.DEADLOCK_NUM = TV.DEADLOCK_NUM AND 
             TP.PROCESS_ID = TV.VICTIM_ID
ORDER  BY DEADLOCK_NUM;

Do you know how to say which query was terminate?

Aside... meaningful aliases might help you to figure out what's going on. The value you're looking for should be at DEADLOCK_GRAPH_XML.value('(/deadlock/victim-list/victimProcess/@id)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)').

@AlwaysLearning This is what I get with TV ... But this does not give which of the two queries involved is the one that has been terminated ! So your remark does not help me !

What is it you're actually looking for then? The input buffer from the victim process so you can see the T-SQL that was submitted for it? e.g.: db<>fiddle. Also be aware that deadlock graphs can contain more than two processes.

@AlwaysLearning But can there be more than one victim?

@wqw I've never observed more than one in any particular XDL. Interleaved lock cycles are broken up in subsequent runs of the Lock Monitor task which normally runs every ~5 seconds to reap deadlocks. When it finds one, though, it temporarily ramps up the checking frequency to as fast as every ~100 milliseconds. Ref: Deadlock detection
